# How to implement adding markers to a map in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a map embedded on my site using "google-map-react". I need to implement adding custom markers to the map. To prescribe coordinates in the code and after saving the marker appears on the map. How can this be implemented?

```js
import GoogleMapReact from "google-map-react";

const Map = () => {
  const defaultProps = {
    center: {
      lat: 10.99835602,
      lng: 77.01502627,
    },
    zoom: 11,
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{ height: "100vh", width: "100%" }}>
        <GoogleMapReact
          bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: "" }}
          defaultCenter={defaultProps.center}
          defaultZoom={defaultProps.zoom}
        ></GoogleMapReact>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Map;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [@react-google-maps/api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-google-maps/api) library and implement it like this:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { GoogleMap, Marker, useJsApiLoader } from '@react-google-maps/api';



const MapComponent = (props) => {

    const { location, zoom } = props;
    
    const containerStyle = {
        width: '100%',
        height: '95vh'
    };

    var { isLoaded } = useJsApiLoader({
        id: 'google-map-script',
        googleMapsApiKey: /* Your API key */
    })

    return isLoaded ?
            <GoogleMap
                mapContainerStyle={containerStyle}
                defaultCenter={location}
                defaultZoom={zoom}
            >
                <Marker
                    position={location}
                />
            </GoogleMap>
        : <></>
}
export default MapComponent;
```

Comment: Can I create custom markers without apiKey?

Comment: in order to use google maps services, you must have a google api key